# VHDL: (vcom-1136: std_logic_vector undefined)

Tags: syntax, vhdl

Getting a seemingly unexplainable syntax error saying that std_logic is undefined, even when it compiles earlier in the code! The first error occurs at the beginning of the entity, or line 37. I believe it has something to do with creating my own package but this is something I have done before and never had this error! Thanks for any help.

```
  library IEEE;
  use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
  use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

  package lab2 is  
  constant SWIDTH: integer := 4;
  subtype state_type is 
    std_logic_vector(SWIDTH-1 downto 0); 

  constant S1: state_type  := "0000"; --these are the "reset states"
  constant S2: state_type  := "0001";
  constant S3: state_type  := "0010";
  constant S4: state_type  := "0011";
  constant S5: state_type  := "0101";
  constant S6: state_type  := "0110";
  constant S7: state_type  := "0111"; -- these are the "show letter" states
  constant S8: state_type  := "1000";
  constant S9: state_type  := "1001";
  constant S10: state_type := "1010";
  constant S11: state_type := "1011";

  constant G : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"47";
  constant a : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"61";
  constant r : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"72";
  constant e : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"65";
  constant send1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"38";
  constant send2 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"0C";
  constant send3 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"01";
  constant send4 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"06";
  constant send5 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"80";

end package;

------------------------------------

entity lab2 is
    port(     key : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  -- pushbutton switches
            sw : in std_logic_vector(8 downto 0);  -- slide switches
            ledg : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            lcd_rw : out std_logic;
            lcd_en : out std_logic;
            lcd_rs : out std_logic;
            lcd_on : out std_logic;
            lcd_blon : out std_logic;
            lcd_data : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
            hex0 : out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0));  -- one of the 7-segment diplays
end lab2 ;
```

the error happens in the port, where it gives that std_logic and std_logic_vector are unknown references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of `IEEE.std_logic_1164.all` is also required before the `entity`, like:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lab2 is
```

The first `IEEE.std_logic_1164.all` only applies to the `package`, and `package body` of the same package, but not to any other design objects like an `entity` or `package`, even if these happens to be in the same file.

This allows for creation of different design objects in the same file, while still controlling the visible objects from libraries and packages.

Comment: This fixes the std_logic errors, but not my defined type state_type is giving me an unknown reference. Do I also have to include the package lab2 somehow?

Comment: I don't see a reference to the `state_type` type outside the `lab2` package, so where do you get the "unknown reference" error?  If you use the `lab2` package `state_type` type in another entity, then add `use work.lab2.all`, or `use work.lab2.all` for reference to `state_type` as `lab2.state_type`.

Comment: Ah sorry it was further down in code I didn't include in the post. That seems to have fixed my errors, thanks a lot!

Comment: In addition to Morten's fine answer there's at least one more thing you'll need to fix. Two primary units (package, entity, configuration) can't have the same simple name in the same library (work). There are two obvious solutions, change the name of package (e.g. lab2_pkg) or put in a separate library. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 13.1 Design units paragraph 5.

Comment: @gurtn: If this is the answer for your question, then please accept the answer by clicking the check mark, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). See more in [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).